# Reading JSON array from cross domain sencha

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I would like to store an array of json objects from another domain. I have tried all possible configurations in the proxy, but it is still not working. So please help with me.

Response Array:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Take A Bow",
    "artist": "Rihanna",
    "cover": "resources/images/cd-covers/take-a-bow.jpeg",
    "audio": "http://home.no/hamed2ganja12/Single/Rihanna%20-%20Take%20A%20Bow%20%28www.Iran2Music.Org%29.mp3"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Ridin' Solo",
    "artist": "Jason Derulo",
    "cover": "resources/images/cd-covers/ridin-solo.jpeg",
    "audio": "http://ms11.cyworld.com.cn/d044/2010/05/01/167/1272686567306986_file.mp3"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Hero",
    "artist": "Nickelback",
    "cover": "resources/images/cd-covers/hero.jpeg",
    "audio": "http://api.ning.com/files/hXzO1QWnGr6ZgtB05IbaLW5IId7mjLPvOMGA0I8JHY*u*ZMCrczyw*XZrimUE7XQHFHgOLWa2b8s0xGfoHg5nRs-J84KlSGO/NickelBackHeroSpidermanTheme.mp3"
}]
```

model:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.model.Track', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
config: {
    fields: [
        { name: 'id',     type: 'int'    },
        { name: 'title',  type: 'string' },
        { name: 'artist', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'cover',  type: 'string' },
        { name: 'audio',  type: 'string' }
    ]
}   
});
```

Store:

```
Ext.create('Ext.data.Store',{
requires:['MyApp.model.Track'],
autoLoad:true,
model:'MyApp.model.Track',
storeId:'myStore',
autoSync:true,
fields:["title","artist"],
proxy:{
type:'jsonp',
url: 'http://www.tux-components.com/examples/playlist/app/music.json',
reader: {
            type: 'json'
            }    
 },
listeners:{
load: function(store, records, successful,operation,eOpts){
console.log('loaded records count is '+store.getCount());
}
}

});
```

I found it is giving timeout error. but the URL is working fine in browser. 
What should i do next? please help me..

Answer (score 0):

The data returned by the remote server needs to be *JSONP*, not *JSON* - the main difference being the callback function that wraps the returned object.

I don't know what framework/version you're using, but read the [JSONP Proxy](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.3.0/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP) API docs very carefully - all of the answers are within!